# Segmentation Fault on jmp instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

For a project, I write a compiler for a specific langage. I have to handle exceptions.
My problem is in the assembly code. I get a segmentation fault on a jmpq instruction and I don't understand why.

This is an extract of the code :

```
    jmpq *.finally_27
    [...]
.finally_27:
    [...]
```

ddd pointed me that it is the line jmp that causes a segmentation fault, but I don't understand why. Why a jmpq instruction can fail ?

The full code is here : 
http://pastebin.com/E2AbW158

The error is at the line 311.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use JMP with a label, you shoudn't include the '*', because otherwise, you are telling: "jump to the address location stored in the quadword beginning at memory address `finally_27`"

And you want: "jump to the address location whose value is `finally_27`" so it is:

`JMP .finally_27`

Not

`JMPQ *.finally_27`